# read_sql_query() using stored procedure and parameters

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

How can I pass a parameter to a SQL Stored Procedure?

I've tried so many ways, but they all fail.

Here is my latest attempt.

The parameter is `BookId`.

Here is my code:

```
bookId = 653

connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=dev;DATABASE=Nemisis"
connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

qry = text("EXECUTE dbo.LibraryBookData @BookId = " & bookId)
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(qry)

df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)
```

This try time I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
    unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

I also tried this:

```
qry = text("EXECUTE dbo.LibraryBookData :BookId")
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(qry, BookId = bookId)
```

Which gave me this error:

```
TypeError: Connection.execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bookId'
```

Comment: `print("foo" & 1)` does not work either. In fact, `&` does not work with text at all. If you want to pass that parameter it goes as part of the call to `execute()`

Comment: Check out: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text

Comment: @JonSG Hi Jon! I did see that page a few days ago.  One of the things I tried was from there and I just edited my question to include it.  Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried `:BookId`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I added new code to my original question

Comment: @snakecharmerb oh sorry, I got this error: "TypeError: Connection.execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bookId'"

Comment: You should pass named parameters as a dictionary, not as keyword arguments. But isn't the point of sqlalchemy to not use raw sql anyway?

Comment: @mkrieger1 re: "But isn't the point of sqlalchemy to not use raw sql anyway?" - SQLAlchemy's [SQL Expression Language](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/expression_api.html) gives us the *option* to avoid using raw SQL, but there are cases where using textual SQL is necessary, and this is one of those cases.

Comment: @Hermann12 no but how would you pass a parameter to the stored procedure from that example?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, does this not [work](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question indicates that you want to use pandas' `read_sql_query()` to retrieve the results into a DataFrame. In that case, use `params=` and pass the parameter values as a dict:

```py
book_id = 653
sql = text("""\
SET NOCOUNT ON;
EXEC dbo.LibraryBookData @BookId = :bookId;
""")
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, params={"bookId": book_id})
```

Note that `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is not always required, but it is a good habit to get into with mssql.